# How did the french postmodernists and Rorty arrive to the same conclusion using different methodology?

Tags: postmodernism, foucault, derrida, rorty

Rorty founded pragmatism -> which is basically that words only get their meanign based on how they're used

French postmodernists on the other hand did different things all attacking Grand narratives (as Lyotard would describe it). Derrida problematized the structuralist method of deriving meaning. Foucault attacked meta-narratives like Sexuality and Physical sciences, showing they're not independent of culture. And Baudrillard too showed the hyperreal becomes more real than the real.

How did these 2 methodologies lead to the same conclusions ?

Comment: What same conclusions?

Comment: See [Rorty](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/rorty/): "the distinctive and controversial brand of Rorty's pragmatism... Rorty has sought to integrate and apply the milestone achievements of Dewey, Hegel and Darwin in a pragmatist synthesis of historicism and naturalism." Thus, Hegel and historicism are "common sources".

Comment: Rorty founded *neo*pragmatism is more accurate, but to call him a pragmatist in any sense is already stretching it. I refer you to Susan Haack. One cannot choose one’s own identity by fiat as he seemed to do.

Comment: At this level of approximation... the notion that "words get their meaning based on how they're used" [pragmatism] and that culture and "grand narratives" produced meaning are not so different. The way that "words are used" is cultural and historical.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Susan Haack dedicated a remarkably large portion of her career to supply evidence, in detail, about Rorty being a fraud. He has the reputation of essentially being a postmodern troll among many other analytic philosophers. His claim he represented any kind of pragmatism is controversial.